# aws ec2 tensorflow gpu not work

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-ec2, keras

I have one aws EC2 (p2.xlarge) with AMI

> Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu) Version 5.0 - ami-7336d50e
>
> Comes with latest binaries of deep learning frameworks pre-installed
> in separate virtual environments: MXNet, TensorFlow, Caffe, Caffe2,
> PyTorch, Keras, Chainer, Theano and CNTK. Fully-configured with NVidia
> CUDA, cuDNN and NCCL

I try to make rnn with keras put when a start my program i have this

```
 I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.7.5 locally
 I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
 I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.7.5 locally
 I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
 I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.7.5 locally
```

after when karas start i have this

```
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:910] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla K80
major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.8235
pciBusID 0000:00:1e.0
Total memory: 11.17GiB
Free memory: 11.10GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 12639 get requests, put_count=6277 evicted_count=1000 eviction_rate=0.159312 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.590395
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:259] Raising pool_size_limit_ from 100 to 110
```

but when de program learn is not fast my macbookpro is faster than my EC2 and i have this warning after each epochs

```
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 4156 get requests, put_count=8233 evicted_count=4000 eviction_rate=0.48585 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.000481232
```

i have install karas_gpu and tensorflow_gpu and i use vm for keras2 with tensorflow

what you can tell me if I do something wrong so that a simple little macbook can be more faster than EC2 with this spec

> p2.xlarge (11.75 ECU, 4 vCPU, 2.7 GHz, E5-2686v4, 61 Gio mémoire, EBS
> uniquement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is simple. In the EC2 AMI (p2.xlarge) the gpu is `Tesla K80` in with TensorFlow this gpu speedups 4x ~ 10x cpu and in my macbook i have 8 cpu.